# How to wait until button's disabled state is changed in testing library?

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I have a React component with a input field and a button disabled at the very beginning. This button's state ( disabled ) changes if input provided by user to input field is validated by API, which is called after anything is typed in input field.

I am testing by providing a valid input but it needs to wait until API's call is completed, so basically i want to test, if on providing a valid input, button get re enabled or not in my test.

I am doing this by following code:

```
userEvent.type(getByRole("textbox"), "HELLO");
await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId("my-btn")).not.toBeDisabled());
```

But its not working even with a valid input

Comment: How are you providing the valid input? Could you add the full code of your test?

Comment: How are you resolving the HTTP request?

Answer (score 6):

You can increase the `waitFor` timeout as [explained in the doc](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor):

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(getByTestId("my-btn")).not.toBeDisabled(), {
  timeout: 5000,
});
```

Beyond 5000 you will probably need also to [increase jest timeout](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestsettimeouttimeout).

Answer (score 0):

For me waiting for a disabled state to dissapear doesn't work. I usually wait for something else to happen in the DOM.

Maybe using the input you typed something in...

```
userEvent.type(getByRole("textbox"), "HELLO");

expect(await expect(screen.getByDisplayValue('HELLO')).toBeInTheDocument()); 

expect(getByTestId("my-btn")).not.toBeDisabled()
```

Also, since you are waiting for the response of an API, you might want to mock the response of that call to something that will remove your disabled state.